# How to add node to ARKit Scene based on where the centre of the device is on button press?

Tags: swift, xcode, arkit

Complete swift beginner struggling to add nodes to scene on tap of a button.

I am aware I can use tap gesture to get the tap coordinates and perform a hit test and then place an object in 3D space where tapped. However I want to show a sphere or crosshair in the centre of device screen and when tap a button at the bottom of the screen have the same behaviour of obtaining the same information a tap gesture would give.(At least i think that is what I need to do here i'm not sure.)

After loading my scene I add a small Sphere to the child node of the camera point of view like this:

```
sphereNode = SCNNode(geometry: SCNSphere(radius: 0.020))
sphereNode?.position = SCNVector3Make(0, 0, -2)
sceneView.pointOfView?.addChildNode(sphereNode!)
```

This places the sphere in the centre of the screen slightly in front of the camera. As I move the device around the room the sphere stays in the middle as expected. I want to be able to tap a button then obtain the information that a tap gesture would give in order to perform a hit test and place a new sphere in the scene at that location. Unless there is another better way of doing this?

The behaviour I am looking for is very similar to that of the iOS measuring app. The measure point stays in the centre of the screen at all times, then on tapping add a new point is added.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach of using [hitTest(_:types:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arframe/2875718-hittest) is the way to go. I think that the linked one, from `ARSession`, is the most straightforward.

Since you want to hit test from the center of the screen, and the `CGPoint` argument expected by `hitTest(_:types:)` is in normalized coordinate space, from (0.0, 0.0) to (1.0, 1.0), all you need to do is pass (0.5, 0.5).

Here is some code:

```
func buttonAction() {
  guard let currentFrame = session.currentFrame,
    let hitTest = currentFrame.hitTest(CGPoint(x: 0.5, y: 0.5), types: .featurePoint).last else {
    return
  }
  let anchor = ARAnchor(transform: hitTest.worldTransform)
  session.add(anchor: anchor)
}
```

After the anchor is added, you can add the node using `ARSCNViewDelegate`'s method [renderer(_:nodeFor:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnviewdelegate/2865801-renderer). Basically, this method is going to be called when you add an anchor to the session.

By the way, since it seems that you're using [ARSCNView](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arscnview), you can access your AR session like this `sceneView.session`.